# Where clause syntactically correct, but giving nothing

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using this tutorial table called practice, with columns `DEPTNO DNAME LOC` respectively.

```
10  ACCOUNTING  NEW YORK
20  RESEARCH    DALLAS
30  SALES       CHICAGO
40  OPERATIONS  BOSTON
```

Given this query

```
select * from practice where loc = 'DALLAS'
```

I get a row that I was expecting, but playing around, I also did this query,

```
select * from practice where('LOC') = 'DALLAS'
```

and I get nothing. I don't understand, this latter query is syntactically valid, I got no exceptions, but still got an empty set result set. Does `where` with `()` do anything special?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression:

```
where('LOC') = 'DALLAS'
```

is comparing the string `'LOC'` to the string `'DALLAS'`.  These do not match.

The expression:

```
where loc = 'DALLAS'
```

is comparing the column `loc` to the string `'DALLAS'`.  Apparently, these do sometimes match.

The single quotes are related to the problem.  The parentheses have nothing to do with it.  (They do something "special" that is unrelated to your problem.  They group expressions for evaluation purposes.)

Comment: Thanks! So to clarify, I thought that the purpose of the `where` clause is to check the column values. Why would the `where` clause be used to check individual strings?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian . . . The `where` clause checks the conditions that you put into it.  In fact, it is rather common to do something like `where v_city is null or city = v_city` to compare the column `city` to the variable `v_city`.  The first part is comparing two "constant" values.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause just checks boolean expressions, these can be conditions on columns, but can also be more complex conditions - or more simple ones like comparing strings.